# Can jsp .tag files be included via a tld file like Java TagSupport classes?

Tags: jsp, tags, tld

Most of my tags are done with .tag files, as its much easier to work with html that way. However, my web applications expect these tags in the web.xml/tags directory, which is a pain when a tag is shared among multiple web apps.

If i understand correct, a java tag class that extends TagSupport can include the tld in the source code, and the tag can be imported easily. Can I do something like that for my .tag files so I can keep them in a shared parent project and not worry about copying them to individual tag folders in my web applications? Is there a way for a tld to point to a .tag file on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) says:

> Tag files can be placed in one of two locations: in the /WEB-INF/tags/
>   directory or subdirectory of a web application or in a JAR file (see
>   Packaged Tag Files) in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of a web
>   application. Packaged tag files require a tag library descriptor (see
>   Tag Library Descriptors), an XML document that contains information
>   about a library as a whole and about each tag contained in the
>   library.

and

> Tag files can be packaged in the /META-INF/tags/ directory in a JAR
>   file installed in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of the web application.
>   Tags placed here are typically part of a reusable library of tags that
>   can be used easily in any web application.
>
> Tag files bundled in a JAR require a tag library descriptor. Tag files
>   that appear in a JAR but are not defined in a TLD are ignored by the
>   web container.
>
> When used in a JAR file, the path subelement of the tag-file element
>   specifies the full path of the tag file from the root of the JAR.
>   Therefore, it must always begin with /META-INF/tags/.